# Collecting loop result from each loop cycle

Tags: matlab

I am currently writing the code in order to collect the average value for centroids coordinate inside a while loop for each video frame.
For each loop cycle there will be only one average value as the output for each single frame. My objective is to collect all the average values and plot it out.

```
for object = 1:length(centroid);

        centX = centroid(1,object); 
        centY = centroid(2,object);    
        vidIn = step(htextinsCent, vidIn, [centY centX], [centY-6 centX-9]); %this line is for coordinate display purpose on each frame

end   

for object =   length(centroid)>0;   

        columncentroid=centroid';
        average=mean(columncentroid);
end
```

I am having difficulty to list all the average values from all the frames at the end of code run.The earlier average value is replaced by latest value after each loop.
Kindly advice me for appropiate steps. Thank you in advanced.

Comment: What is the intent of the line 'for object = length(centroid)>0' ?

Comment: You took the words right out of my mouth @grantnz! It appears that you will only execute that second loop once, since length(centroid) will be a single value.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you already have a 2xN array of centroid values; all you have to do is display them. If you want to have the average of all values, you do

```
average = mean(centroid');
```

This takes the mean over the first dimension - which after transpose is all the X values in the first column and the Y values in the second columns. `average` should be a 2 element row vector after this operation.

```
display(average);
```

will tell you what the values are.

It *seems* that this is what you want, and you did everything right (except with that inexplicable loop around it...). If this is not what you need, please explain more clearly in your question!

Answer (score 0):

To keep all averages, you can write:

```
average = []; %init average as empty
for object = length(centroid):-1:1;   

    columncentroid=centroid';
    average= [average mean(columncentroid(:,object))]; %add new average to the end of average array
end
```

Comment: But this loop only ever runs once anyway, so why bother concatenating? Also since `columncentroid` is not changed in the "loop", you would just be concatenating the same number over and over again (that is if this was a loop i.e. ran more than once)